# How to showing folder with counting files in that every folders on terminal linux

Tags: linux, terminal

this is my structure folder

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

I have files in folders and counting that like this

```
ls folder1 | wc -l
```

And result is only counting files in that folder

But, i want to show folders include many files in once command

This my expectation result:

```
folder1 100 files 
folder2 200 files 
folder3 300 files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for dir in $(find . -type d); do
    echo "`basename ${dir}`: $(find ${dir} -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)"
done
```